# Will having an iFrame on someone else's domain transfer pagerank to my site?

Tags: iframe, seo, pagerank

I am having a hard time finding a good answer to this question.  I see that Google treats the content in the iframe as its own seperate site, but what I want to know is if it transfers any pagerank to my site.  What I am letting other sites embed is an interactive javascript app.

I have an iframe embed that looks something like

```
<iframe width='895' height='656' src='http://domain.com/script.php?var=whatever' scrolling="no" style='border:none;'>Stuff about the <a href='http://domain.com/other_page'>Keywords</a> and my site.</iframe>
```

Will the link inside the iframe tags transfer pagerank to me or no?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The pagerank at the best of my knowledge is forwarded just in the case of link.